# jQuery val() Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's been a while since I've coded in jQuery, but this is an issue I don't remember happening before. I have a simple form:

```
    <form id="location">
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Enter your city" required="required">
        <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Enter your zip code" required="required">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="GET Weather" id="submit">
    </form>
```

and a call to get the value of the inputs:

```
    <script>
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var city = $('#city').val();
        var zip = $("#zip").val();
    });
    console.log(city);
    console.log(zip);
    </script>
```

And for some reason I'm getting the HTML returned back of the two inputs as so-

```
        <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Enter your zip code" required="required">
```

Why am I not getting back the values of the inputs?

Comment: What with the down vote? Don't shoot people down for trying to learn coding =/

Comment: place the console.log calls inside the event handler, and wrap everything in the document.ready() as in `$(function() {
    your code;
});` out of JQuery Documentation:`A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you.` - https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: At least related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS is function-scoped. Your 2 variables don't exist outside the `.submit()` function. You have to put the 2 console.logs there.

Also, the function is triggered only when submit is called. You were basically printing the console.logs before that.

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var city = $('#city').val();
    var zip = $("#zip").val();
    console.log(city, zip);
});
```

Comment: I was scratching my head for quite awhile trying to figure this out. Like I said, its been a while. There was also some issue with my submit button, but I got that fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please define these 2 variables in global scope or print these two values inside function like,

```
<script>
    var city ="", zip ="";
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        city = $('#city').val();
        zip = $("#zip").val();
        show();
    });

   function show(){
    console.log(city);
    console.log(zip);
  }  
</script>
```

or simply,

```
   $('#submit').click(function() {
        var city = $('#city').val();
        var zip = $("#zip").val();
    console.log(city);
    console.log(zip);    
});
```

Currently, where you print values it is outside scope of those two variables.
Also, I see there is no action attribute in your form.